# When exactly can I use the expectation operator?

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am working on a parser with boost spirit x3. I finished the grammar and the parser parses as expected. Now I want to add error handling, so I have to add expectation points to my grammar.
My question is when exactly can I use the expectation operator `>` instead of the "followed by" operator `>>`? 
Can I only use it like `a > b` if `a >> b` never happens in another part of the grammar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expectation operator essentially disables back-tracking. If `b` must always follow `a`, it is a good time to use an expectation point : `>`. If there is some combination of logic that can result in an `a` followed by something else, you should not use expectation but instead `>>`.

If you have alternatives in your grammar, you will want to pay special attention that you have not defeated valid back tracks.

For example, if you are writing a language parser that requires the conditional expression of an if statement to be in parenthesis, a valid grammar might include:

`if_statement = lit("if") > '(' > statement > ')';`

`if` is a keyword and it must be followed by a `(`. Perhaps there is whitespace between the `if` and `(` but the keyword `if` must be followed by a `(`.

(Note: the reality is that the grammar is a little more complex than that. For `if` to be a keyword it can't just match some token that starts with the letter i and f)

You can use `a > b` in your grammar if you know at the point that the rule is encountered an `a` must always be followed by a `b`. You might have a `a >> b` somewhere else in the overall grammar.

Comment: Worth noting that mixing `>` and `>>` can complicate automatic attribute propagation and transformation quite a bit (in relation to the literal question _"When exactly can I use the expectation operator?"_). The problem is that `vector3<int, char, double>` can become e.g. `vector2<vector2<int, char>, double>` in such cases

Comment: @sehe I don't have much experience with X3, and so sadly I can't say for sure, but I seem to remember Joel de Guzman saying that this problem, which gave lots of headaches in Qi, is already solved in X3. PS: [Found the link to the statement](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Unexpected-behavior-using-versus-tp4662087p4662153.html).